# How can I set the prefix of routes from resources to resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a rails routes config like that, and when I run `rake routes` it show that, but I wanna the perfix is restore_link, how can I do it?

## rake routes

```
restore_links POST   /:uid/links/:id(.:format)                   links#restore
```

## routes config

```
resources :accounts, path: '/', param: :uid, only: [:show] do
  member do
    resources :links do
      collection do
        post ':id', to: "links#restore", as: "restore"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: did you get this one working?

Comment: No, I finially use `post ':uid/links/:id', to: "links#restore", as: "restore_link"` outside the resources block

Comment: I wanna customized perfix not url path

Answer (score 3):

```
resources :accounts, path: '/', param: :uid, only: [:show] do
  member do
    resources :links, path: 'restore_links' do # <========= `path` option
      collection do
        post ':id', to: "links#restore", as: "restore"
      end
    end
  end
end
```